# Why is PHPUnit reporting wrong uid (0 instead of 1000) and how do I fix this?

Tags: php, phpunit, vagrant

I'm writing unit tests for my library and I've found something I don't understand.

PHPunit is reporting uid 0 instead of 1000 when calling the function getmyuid().
I'm running as user 'vagrant' and regular code is reporting the correct uid (1000).

PHPUnit test code (tests/UidTest.php):

```
<?php
class UidTest extends \PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase
{
    public function test_uid_1000(): void
    {
        $this->assertEquals(1000, getmyuid());
    }

    public function test_uid_0(): void
    {
        $this->assertEquals(0, getmyuid());
    }
}
```

> phpunit tests/UidTest.php

yields:

> UidTest::test_uid_1000 Failed asserting that 0 matches expected 1000.

My regular script (testuid.php) reports the correct uid:

```
<?php
var_dump(getmyuid());
```

> php testuid.php

yields:

> int(1000)

My questions are:

**Why is getmyuid() in phpunit reporting uid 0 instead of 1000?**

**How can I force getmyuid() in phpunit to report the correct uid 1000?**

Comment: What does `getmyuid()` do exactly?

Comment: @Andrei getmyuid() returns the user id of the current user running the script. As I run from CLI as user 'vagrant', it should report 1000. http://php.net/manual/en/function.getmyuid.php

Comment: I'm assuming user `vagrant` also owns the file?

Comment: @Andrei Yes, vagrant owns both tests/UidTest.php and testuid.php

Comment: You're running the tests from inside the vagrant machine?

Comment: @Andrei yes, I am, both for 'phpunit tests/UidTest.php' and 'php testuid.php'

Comment: I got nothing. I expected something related to how the tests are run. Outside the machine I suppose it would make sense for uid to be 0, but since you're running the inside the mahcine...well.

Comment: @Andrei What do you mean by 'I got nothing'? Have you run this in vagrant? And do you have the correct user id reported by getmyuid()?